# Python Scrapy issue with URL generation

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I have an issue with Scrapy. 
I want to scrap a list of N url (in the same website) but i don't know what URL will work or not. In fact I want to "search" something on the site, a road - village - county. 
If i tell the website to search for road+village+county he may not find anything. If he didn't find what i want, i will do a more "global" search, by searching only village+county and finally only county. 
Example: i have the location:

> "D 32, Serrières-de-Briord, Belley, Ain, Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes". Here
>   we have [Road = D 32], [Serrières-de-Briord : (the precise and small)
>   commune] , [Belley: (the nearest and big) commune], [Ain: Department],
>   [Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes: Region].

What I want to do is:
to search

> D 32+Serrières-de-Briord+Belley+Ain+Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes

If there is no result, search for:

> Serrières-de-Briord+Belley+Ain+Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes.

If there is no result, search for

> Belley+Ain+Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes

(usually, at this point it's OK).

The thing is that i want to do this for 25 000 locations. So i can't give scrapy 25000*3 = 75 000 URL to scrap. And the issue is also to avoid Scrapy scraping multiples times the same informations. 
Therefore, what i want to do is to : 
start_url = [all URL at the most precise level - 25 ] 
for url in start_url: 
if there is not what i want : go scrap "url1" (which is built from url, but is more precise). 
if url1 doesn't have what i want: go scrap "url2" (built from url1, and at this point it should be ok).
If i have a good "url" , go parse() (and take the info that i need).

Here is my code :

```
    import scrapy

    from scrapy.http import Request 
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "street"

        start_urls = [
            'http://prix-immobilier.lemonde.fr/prix-immobilier/recherche?q=rue+des+colonnes+du+trone+Paris+Ile-de-France+75012',
            'http://prix-immobilier.lemonde.fr/prix-immobilier/recherche?q=Route+Badevel+à+Saint-Dizier%2C+Badevel%2C+Montbéliard',
        ]

        def start_requests(self):
            for urly in self.start_urls:
                yield Request(url=urly,callback=self.enjoy)

        def enjoy(self,response):
            if response.css("#price_container h1::text").extract_first()[:4]=="Prix":
                yield Request(url=urly,callback=self.parse)
            else:
                pass


        def parse(self,response):
            I parse the info...
```

Here the "enjoy" part is to select only the url that are interesting and "pass" the others. But, this script doesn't work. I get this error:

```
line 27, in enjoy
    yield Request(url=urly,callback=self.parse)
NameError: name 'urly' is not defined
```

and I don't know how can i say to search for another URL that i create from the previous one in case of i didn't find anything (instead of "pass" only...).

I hope my issue is sufficiently clear.
Thanks for your help !

Comment: 75.000 requests sound ok to me, why wouldn't you do that?

Comment: if i create url-url1-url2, and if Scrapy is successful in scraping info of url, he will also scrape url1 and url2 so i will have 3 infos and it's not convenient. I search firstly for the most precise thing. But if i can't have it, i said "OK let's have a little more general one, and i will said that this value will be the value of the "precise" location". As an example: if i don't have "Serrières-de-Briord" but I have "Belley", i will catch the value of "Belley" and put it as the value of " Serrières-de-Briord".  But, in case of "Serrières-de-Briord" works, i don't need additional value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass along your search parameters via `meta`.

For example, in `start_requests`, instead of yielding from a URL list (`self.start_urls`), you could use list of lists of search parameters.
Below is a toy spider using httpbin.org to issue request with each 3-params, then the last 2, then the last one:

```
from w3lib.url import add_or_replace_parameter
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "street"

    base_search_url = 'http://httpbin.org/get'
    search_params = [
        ['C', 'B', 'A'],
        ['F', 'E', 'D'],
    ]

    def _build_search_request(self, params):
        url = add_or_replace_parameter(
            self.base_search_url,
            'q',
            ' '.join(params)
        )
        return scrapy.Request(url, meta={'params': params},
            callback=self.parse)

    def start_requests(self):
        for params in self.search_params:
            yield self._build_search_request(params)

    def parse(self, response):
        if 'ok' in response.text:
            # parse_info
            # ...
            pass
        else:
            params = response.meta['params']
            params.pop(0)
            if params:
                yield self._build_search_request(params)
```

Notice how the search params are passed with each request in the `meta` dict.